# Regex with a word boundary in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to captcha a particular string with a regex, however I am losing the first char.

The string is
(06)12345678

My regex is

```
r'\b\((0[34679]{1})\)?([\- ]{0,1})[0-9]{3,4}([\- ]{0,1})[0-9]{3,5}'
```

but all I get in my match is

```
06)12345678
```

I really want that first ( also.

The ( and ) are conditional because sometimes there wont be ().
but the word boundary are there to prevent numbers like

```
hello123456789
```

matching

```
regex = r'\b\(?(0[34679]{1})\)?([\- ]{0,1})[0-9]{3,4}([\- ]{0,1})[0-9]{3,5}'
matches = re.finditer(regex, '(06)12345678)')
for match in matches:
    print match.group(0)
```

any thoughts?

-- examples --

```
(06)12345678 should match, (06)12345678
06 12345678 should match, 06 12345678
1234567890 should match, 1234567890
=12345678 no match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escape second "(", not first one, and the last but one ")" before first `?`.

Live demo: https://regex101.com/r/5h3FBr/1

Comment: Not quite, it didn't work I just ended up with 12345678 it didn't include the (06) at the start.

Comment: Thanks for the refiddle, however if you change it from (06) to, 12345678 then it doesn't match. The () are optional. Hence the /(? on each one. Examples added to the question.

Comment: Nearly there, the last one shouldn't match, which is where the whole word boundary came into it (see OP). So =12345678 should not match